# Is it possible to combine these 2 statements using linq?

Tags: asp.net, linq

Using Asp.Net 4.0/C#

I have a list of items. The list contains duplicates.

This is the item class:

```
public class PingtreeNode
{
    public int TierId { get; set; }
    public int LenderId { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int Seq { get; set; }

    public PingtreeNode(int tierId, int lenderId, int weight, int seq)
    {

        TierId = tierId;
        LenderId = lenderId;
        Weight = weight;
        Seq = seq;
    }
}
```

In the first instance I want to select the first item for each LenderId. I do so using this linq:

```
var tierNodes = new List<PingtreeNode>();    
tierNodes = tierNodes.GroupBy(x => x.LenderId).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

However, I also want to add a sequence to the list, starting 1,2,3 etc. I currently do this separately by looping through like this:

```
            int seq = 1;
            foreach (var t in tierNodes)
            {
                t.Seq = seq;
                seq++;
            }
```

Is is possible to both group and sequence at the same time using a single linq statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int seq = 1;
var tierNodes = new List<PingtreeNode>();    
tierNodes = tierNodes
    .GroupBy(x => x.LenderId)
    .Select(x => { var y = x.First(); y.Seq = seq++; return y; })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Some methods of enumerable have an index parameter on the selector function. One of them is [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534869.aspx).

You can use that index parameter for the sequencing number:

```
var tierNodes = new List<PingtreeNode>();    
tierNodes = tierNodes
    .GroupBy(x => x.LenderId)
    .Select((x, i) => { var y = x.First(); y.Seq = i + 1; return y; })
    .ToList();
```

This will give you an enumerable independent of any outside variables, thus being idempotent, and without any closures.